# Insertar filas dentro de mi tbody de mi tabla

Tags: html, jquery

Cuando envio las filas a mi tabla no se insertan dentro de mi tbody como se muestra aqui:[image: tbody]

El codigo que utilizo es:

```
$('#mytable tbody').after(fila);
```

Fila es mi arreglo de datos.
Que debo cambiar para que lo incorpore dentro de tbody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con el metodo `.append()`, te dejo un ejemplo para que mires la aplicación el *append()*:

```js
$('.btnAgregar').on('click', () => {

  let filas = 
  `<tr>
      <td>Dato 1</td>
      <td>Dato 2</td>
    </tr>`;
    
    $('#mytable tbody').append(filas);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Titulo 1</th>
      <th>Titulo 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btnAgregar">Agregar filas</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agregarlos con las funciones append(fila) o html(fila) para remplazar el contenido

```
$('#mytable tbody').append(fila);
```

o remplaza el contenido de tbody

```
 $('#mytable tbody').html(fila);
```

Comment: Gracias, no intente ese manera ya que cuando lo usaba en otros arrglos que hago borraba el contenido y temina que cada vez que agrege un item se borre el anterior pero no xd. Gracias man